# PySpark script succeeds for 1GB file, fails for 20GB file - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I'm using PySpark and spark-submit in order to read and manipulate CSV files with headers.

First operations are related to truncating some columns, casting to integer types, etc.

The main operation is using `groupBy` in order to calculate statistical measures of a column, based on another column value.

When I run my script on **1GB file**, It works perfectly!
Problem is, when running it on **20GB file**, it fails, as far as I can understand because of errors in `groupBy`.

Both files have the same format and exact same columns, e.g.:

```
TRANSACTION_URL    START_TIME        END_TIME           SIZE    FLAG  COL6 COL7 ...
www.google.com     20170113093210    20170113093210     150      1    ...  ...
www.cnet.com       20170113114510    20170113093210     150      2    ...  ...
```

Only the first file contain X transactions, and the 2nd contains a hell of a lot more (20GB records).

**ERROR Log:** (Errors start in line 32)

[pastebin link for error log](http://pastebin.com/Q0BGndkW)

**My Script:**

```
import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, stddev, regexp_replace, col

sc = SparkContext('local[*]')
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

print ('** Script Started: %s **' % str(datetime.datetime.now()))  # Analysis Start Time

print "Loading file... ",
log_df = sqlContext.read.format('csv').\
    options(header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter='\t', dateFormat='yyyyMMddHHmmss').\
    load("hdfs:/user/BGU/logs/01_transactions.log")  # Load data file
print "Done!\nAdjusting data to fit our needs... ",

'''
Manipulate columns to fit our needs:
'''
size_col = 'DOWNSTREAM_SIZE'
flag_col = 'CONGESTION_FLAG'
url_col = 'TRANSACTION_URL'

log_df = log_df.filter(~log_df[url_col].rlike("(SNI.*)")).\
    withColumn(flag_col, regexp_replace(col(flag_col), "(;.*)", "").
               cast(IntegerType()))
log_df = log_df.withColumn(size_col, log_df[size_col].cast(IntegerType()))

print "done!\n\n** %s Statistical Measures **\n" % size_col

'''
Calculations:
    DOWNSTREAM_SIZE statistics:
    In accordance to CONGESTION_FLAG value
'''
log_df.cache().groupBy(flag_col).agg(mean(size_col).alias("Mean"), stddev(size_col).alias("Stddev")).\
    withColumn("Variance", pow(col("Stddev"), 2)).show(3, False)

print ('** Script Ended: %s **' % str(datetime.datetime.now()))  # Analysis End Time
```

If any more info is needed please tell me and I'll provide it.

Thanks

Comment: Try setting date format in options `dateFormat='yyyyMMddHHmmss'` [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features). BTW you can use spark inbuilt CSV parser as you are working with **2.0+**.

Comment: What do you mean by `setting date format in options`? how to use it exactly? spark is very new to me.


And what is spark inbuilt CSV parser? isn't it the 'com.databricks.spark.csv' i'm currently using? my cmd is `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 ./script.py`

Comment: Usage `options(header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter='\t', dateFormat='yyyyMMddHHmmss').`.

Comment: **isn't it the 'com.databricks.spark.csv' i'm currently using?** It's the same code. But it moved to spark sql from 2.0 on wards. Finally code should be `format('csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter='\t', dateFormat='yyyyMMddHHmmss')` and **no need to add** `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0` in command, It can be `spark-submit ./script.py`.

Comment: That's good to know, i'll give it a try.
Regarding `dateFormat`, why should it matter? i'm not using the time columns in my script currently

Comment: @mrsrinivas I've just tried with dateFormat and using spark inbuilt csv parser as you suggested, still get the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the errors was some 'bad' records, I guess.

By adding `mode='DROPMALFORMED'` to the CSV parsing options,
The problem was resolved and the script completed without errors.